# Random variable that is undefined on part of the sample space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ be a probability space. Then a random variable $X$ is a function $X:\Omega\to E$ where $(E,F)$ is another measurable space.

**My question is, is there a meaningful interpretation/application of random variables that are undefined on part of the sample space?** That is, $X$ maps $B\to E$ where $B\subsetneq \Omega$. Or alternatively: $X:\Omega\to E\cup\{\text {"Undefined"}\}$.

Are there known examples of such random variables, perhaps in practical applications?

Bonus: If this is at all practically relevant: How do we deal with such random variables? e.g. it seems we can't directly calculate the expectation.

Comment: What is the context of your question?

Comment: For the question to be "interresting" you must have that $\Omega\setminus B$ has non-zero measure. Or put it onether way, if $E$ is defined almost surely it would not be very significant exception...

Comment: Also given a measurable space $E$ you can make $E^*$ (being $E$ with an extra element) a measurable space (by assigning the singleton of the extra element arbitrary measure). So you can certainly make your second interpretation fulfill the definition of a random variable.

Comment: If there is a natural extension to the entire sample space then use it.

Comment: @uniquesolution, the context is that I'm exploring this topic in an open ended manner. It may or may not turn out to be relevant, and the answer will likely increase my understanding. i.e. there is not really a very specific context.

Comment: Also I don't think the definition guarantees that you have a meaningful way to define expectation anyway...

Comment: @skyking, Thank you, that makes sense. I hope someone knows if there are actual interesting examples of this.

Comment: Also, one might consider that a random variable is often mapping the result of a random experiment, say the standard coin flip. Maybe you are only recording coin flips that land on the table and so $X$ is "undefined" on the part of the sample space corresponding to when the coin lands on the floor, but there is an obvious extension to it.